# Group columns in a barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have this script that takes on the `all_data` and set it as a matrix with 4 rows and 4 columns. Then, I am going to plot the data as a bar plot. The thing is that I want to group the bars in the plot by 4 elements. In another word, I want to group the bars by each row. A row is composed with 4 elements, and I want that the respective columns be together. How can I do this with R? I also would like that at each column would have a tick line in the x axis that indicates where are the columns? This way, I know where are the columns with the `0` value.

```
all_data <- c(0, 75, 33, 195, 90, 0, 939, 240, 87, 931, 0,  200, 37, 186, 196, 0)

# Graph data as a bar plot, but gather the columns by a set of 4 elements
barplot(t(as.matrix(all_data, nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)), main=NULL, ylab= "Throughput (Mbps)", xlab="From:", ylim=c(0,1000), beside=TRUE, lwd=1:2, angle=c(45,135), density=seq(5,40,10), col=NA)
box()
grid(NA, 5, lwd=1,lty=5) # grid only in y-direction
```

Comment: Are you looking for: `all_data_matrix <- matrix(all_data, nrow = 4, ncol = 4); barplot(all_data_matrix)`?

Comment: Perhaps   yaRrr from github?

Comment: @maloneypatr I don't want stacked columns. I want them side by side. If you run my script, you will see that all the columns are separated. I want to group them by a set of 4 columns. 4 columns side-by-side, a gap, 4 more columns side-by-side, etc...

Comment: This? `all_data <- c(0, 75, 33, 195, 90, 0, 939, 240, 87, 931, 0,  200, 37, 186, 196, 0); all_data <- matrix(all_data, nrow = 4, ncol = 4); barplot(t(all_data), main=NULL, ylab= "Throughput (Mbps)", xlab="From:", ylim=c(0,1000), beside=TRUE, lwd=1:2, angle=c(45,135), density=seq(5,40,10), col=NA)`